# Magento - Only 20 Products show, the rest are disappearning from Database and Front End

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, product, categories

I have a local install of magento 1.7.0.2

I have all the categories set up, and I'm importing products in through the import/export->dataflow->Import All Products method.

The problem that I'm having is that I'm trying to import some products, they all share the same parent category, but exist in 2 sub categories.  The problem is that it will not show more than 20 total products across the subcategories.  Not only does it not show in the front end, it doesn't show in the backend either.  For example if I import 8 products with 9,15 as the category codes, then I import 16 with 9,16 as the category codes, then it shows 4 products in 9,15, and 16 in 9,16, if I do it the other direction, it shows 12 items in 9,16 and 8 items in 9,15.  I've also tried importing them all at once, and it still only shows 20 products over the 2 subcategories.

Any advice?

(Please ask if any more info is needed, I'm a total magento noob but I'll answer as thoroughly as I can)

Thanks!

Comment: have you checked if your csv is correct, there might be duplicated product ids in it, if its correct try to delete all products and try importing again... oh and always clear your cache

Comment: I did check the csv, the SKU field are all different, although there are things like "AD 56789-01" and "AD 56789-02", but those actually show up.  I've deleted and re-imported a lot of times.  I thought I cleared the cache, maybe I did it wrong, do you have quick steps?

Comment: I figured it out, apparently I hadn't checked the sku field well enough